# Make ImageView fullscreen on click

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, fullscreen

I have a view with two images

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_section"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/top_image"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_text"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_section"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_image"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to make it so that if user clicks image view it becomes full screen and rotates properly to take up full screen.

So far I have tried (for example if top section is clicked)

```
topText.setVisibility(View.GONE)
bottomSection.setVisibility(View.GONE)
getSupportActionBar().hide();
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But image is not really full screen. How would I go about making image full screen? I have been thinking of maybe having one third image view and make that be match parent for width and height and have it become visible on click.

Comment: you are giving image height 170dp. make match_parent to top_image

Answer (score 1):

Create another activity called `ImageZoomedActivity`, pass the image data to it through the intent (it could be an url, local file location etc..) and in the `OnCreate` method :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup_photo_full);
    supportPostponeEnterTransition();
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("file")) {
        imageFile = new File(getIntent().getStringExtra("file"));
        GlideApp.with(this).asBitmap()
                .load(imageFile)
                .into(image);
        supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
    }
```

The code above works with a local file URI passed through the intent.

These two lines

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

let you make the activity in full screen.
It's possible, also, to make a transition between the first activity with the thumbnail and the second one with the full-screen image. If you want to know more send me a pm, I can send you the detailed code to do that.

Comment: Can't really pm you since SO doesn't support communication between users or networking. Any chance you can post a link to github or something?

Comment: I will post in on pastebin, not sure I can do it today though! I’ll definitely do it by tomorrow 

Comment: @Quillion
Activity A code: https://pastebin.com/TvrXwCnc
Activity B (detailed) code: https://pastebin.com/RSPLUe8F

To make the transition working correctly take a look at this: https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50